# How to change VestaCP admin default port

Tags: linux, server, centos

I want to change **VestaCP** admin default port 8083 to 8342

I was edit editor

```
/usr/local/vesta/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

and change to

```
# Vhost
    server {
        listen   8083;
```

to

```
# Vhost
    server {
        listen   8342;
```

and run command

`> service vesta restart`

but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log into your Vesta Control Panel
2. Go to Firewall, add new port (for example 1234) to "Vesta" Rule (default 8083), like so:
   [image]

3. Log into the server via ssh
4. `sudo nano /usr/local/vesta/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`
locate `listen 8083;` and replace it with `listen 1234;`
5. Go back to vesta firewall rule, remove the old port and leave only the new.
6. `sudo service vesta restart`

That's it

Answer (score 0):

**First step:**

v-update-sys-vesta-all

**Second step:**

sed -i 's/8083;/1111;/' /usr/local/vesta/nginx/conf/nginx.conf && v-add-firewall-rule ACCEPT 0.0.0.0/0 1111 TCP && service vesta restart

Answer (score 0):

I am using HestiaCP, a fork of VestaCP. This fork has a new CLI command

```
v-change-sys-port
```

that you can use to change the port in a split second. Check this link https://angelright.com/184/how-to-customize-hestia-fork-of-vesta-debian-9 to see how it works.